# The controller for path ... was not found or does not implement IController after migrating application on another server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am getting this error when I migrated one of our applications to another server. It runs on IIS 8 and Windows 2012.

.NET 4.5 and also 3.5 has been installed.

I have tried to install all kinds of stuff on IIS, but nothing has helped.

Interesting part is that it has been working on the old server. Any idea?

`[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/AppMonitor&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)`

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, the reason for that was a wrong host configuration of the database connection. It was pointing to itself with an external IP address. I've replaced it with the internal IP (as the DB is located on the same server) and it worked.

I still don't understand why that wrong error message. Nothing else has changed...

**Edit:** I have restarted the server, maybe that helped.